# How do I approve edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I cannot find the button to approve proposed edits to my questions.  How do I do it?  Every other time I log in I have messages in my inbox to approve the edits (I think that's what it's tell me to do, anyhow.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The page you are taken to when you click on the notification will take you to the page to approve an edit.  If you don't have an option to approve or reject the edit, then it most likely has already been acted on by the time you saw the notification.

Comment: Besides that the *edit(1)* link in the question leads to the edit review.